# Battery wear on small solar powered devices like watches or pocket calculator

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

As I understand, small repeated charges to a battery damages it. How are small electronic devices, like solar powered watches and calculators, designed to deal with this?

Is the battery basically different from li-ion batteries for "bigger" devices, like smartphones, which would get a full charge each day?

Do they have a chip programmed to either use solar or battery, and only charge the battery if it's rather low?

Comment: Do solar powered watches and calculators actually charge the battery? I've never seen a rechargeable battery used. I always assumed they just use battery power whenever solar power is not present? The battery life alone seems to last years, especially on watches so you would never notice a lack of charging.

Comment: @DKNguyen: At least some of them do recharge the battery. In a Casio Tough Solar the battery would only last 10 months without light recharging.

Comment: _"small repeated charges to a battery damages it."_ - you have that backwards. Fully Charging and discharging is what damages a Lithium-ion battery.

Comment: @BruceAbbott: I meant trickle charging, from 99 to 100% and again and again, instead of the smartphone scenario where you might be recharging from 30-40 to 100% once per day.

Answer (score 1):

My "analog" Seiko Solar watch uses a rechargeable battery  [V157-0AA0](https://www.seikowatches.com/ca-en/customerservice/instruction?language=English) according to SEIKO website.

[image]

Since there is no self-heating or high current, the wear factor is extremely low.

You can see the conditions required for operation.  Sor so many years, I have had a failure since receiving this birthday gift.  The same with my SHarp solar calculator, many decades old.  It always works forever from ambient interior light.  I have less kind words to say about my expensive mechanical wrist-action watch.

> Do they have a chip programmed to either use solar or battery, and only charge the battery if it's rather low?

No.

It runs off the battery and the Solar charger manages to maintain sufficient and not excessive charge.

> when the energy stored in the rechargeable
>   battery is reduced to an extremely low level, the second hand starts moving
>   at 2-second intervals instead of the normal 1-second intervals. (Some calibres have no such function.) The watch remains accurate even while the second hand is moving at 2-second intervals.
>
> NOTE ON POWER SUPPLY
>   The battery used in this watch is a rechargeable battery, which is different from ordinary silver oxide batteries. Unlike other disposable batteries such as dry-cell batteries or button cells, this rechargeable battery can be used over and over again by repeating the cycles of discharging and recharging.
>
> The capacity or recharging efficiency of the rechargeable battery may
>   gradually deteriorate for various reasons such as long-term use or usage
>   conditions. Worn or contaminated mechanical parts or degraded oils may
>   also shorten recharging cycles. If the efficiency of the rechargeable battery
>   decreases, it is necessary to have the watch repaired.